# How do I replace one node in an XML file with a node from another XML file?

Tags: ruby, xml, rexml

I have two XML files. The first is:

```
<a>
  <b>
    <c1>1</c1>
  </b>
  <b>
    <c1>2</c1>
  </b>
  <b "id" = "true">
    <c1>3</c1>
    <d "do" ="me"></d>
  </b>
  <b id ="true">
    <c1>4</c1>
  </b>
</a>
```

And the second is:

```
<a>
  <b>
    <c1>5</c1>
  </b>
</a>
```

I want to update an element from first.xml:

```
<b "id" = "true">
  <c1>3</c1>
  <d "do" ="me"></d>
</b>
```

with an element from second.xml:

```
<b>
<c1>5</c1>
</b>
```

I tried to achieve that by deleting all the `<b>` nodes from first.xml and add the node `<b>` taken from second.xml file. I am able to delete all the nodes `<b>` but not able get an element from second.xml and add that to the first.xml.

Comment: Why not show the code you used? Did you use regex, or a parser? If so, which one?

Comment: That's not well-formed XML. Attribute names should not be quoted. Instead of `<b "id" = "true">` it should be `<b id="true">`.

Comment: Also, you'll need to be specific about how you want to update the first file. Are you looking to append a node, add numbers, or what? It would be best if you provide an example of the output you are expecting.

Comment: I used REXML.
I need to get an element that is more than 2 level deep. 
i searched almost all the apis available in 
http://www.germane-software.com/software/rexml_doc/ 
but i didnt find any api that will help me get the particular element so that i can add it. even in add element, the api is not clear with data about where the element is added

Comment: Part of the problem is the XML is not correct as @Mark Thomas pointed out. In a validating parser that can cause problems. Nokogiri is the HTML/XML parser I'd recommend over REXML.

Comment: thanks the tin man. but occurring first is not my search criteria, the presence of attr id="true" and child <d "do" ="me"></d> is the searching criteria !! Also there might be 2 of those entries and then they both need to be updated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After cleaning up the source XML, this seems to be what you're looking for:

```
xml1 = <<EOT
<a>
  <b>
    <c1>1</c1>
  </b>
  <b>
    <c1>2</c1>
  </b>
  <b id="true">
    <c1>3</c1>
    <d do="me"></d>
  </b>
  <b id="true">
    <c1>4</c1>
  </b>
</a>
EOT

xml2 = <<EOT
<a>
  <b>
    <c1>5</c1>
  </b>
</a>
EOT

require 'nokogiri'

doc1 = Nokogiri::XML(xml1)
doc2 = Nokogiri::XML(xml2)

doc1_b = doc1.at('//b[@id="true"]/c1/..')
doc2_b = doc2.at('b')

doc1_b.replace(doc2_b)

puts doc1.to_html
```

Which outputs:

```
<a>
  <b>
    <c1>1</c1>
  </b>
  <b>
    <c1>2</c1>
  </b>
  <b>
    <c1>5</c1>
  </b>
  <b id="true">
    <c1>4</c1>
  </b>
</a>
```

`doc1.at('//b[@id="true"]/c1/..')'` means "find the first occurrence of a `b` tag with `id="true"` with a child `c1` node".

Comment: This is a good answer. However the XPath @bicepjai wants is more like `//b[@id="true" and d/@do="me"]` and he'll need to iterate through all matches.

Comment: We don't know that. His question isn't clear and he says "an element", not "all elements".

Comment: We do know that, because he responded as such to you, except in the wrong place (read his last comment to his own question). :)

Answer (score 0):

the option
//b[@id="true" and d/@do="me"]

with the above answer answers my question